# Replacing foundation piers. How's this temporary shoring/support of our home?

Tags: framing, structural, construction

We're having piers underneath our house replaced. Temporary shoring is the responsibility of the contractor.

Any thoughts on this? For perspective, this is holds 2 stories, 14' span. My biggest concern is the right corner, which obviously has zero support (left side original pier is still in place). Can that corner hold itself up without any support? Contractor is saying it's fine and "could be like this for years".

https://imgur.com/a/llkSTPD

We're expecting heavy rain for the next week, so it's going to be like this for a while.

Comment: Its hard to know. Can you see any nails on the post or the foot?  Does the contractor have insurance?

Comment: I would check the contractors insurance and license.  Not saying it is bad or good, but you want to have someone with money to cover you.

Comment: If you had a laser or a good bubble stick (and patience), you could make reference marks of what's level and take photos of the before and after. Take lots of interior photos/video as well -- concentrate on corners, tops of windows/doors. Take video of your windows functioning well. Take video of your doors opening and closing and note the reveal between door and jamb. If it goes south, you don't want the contractor coming back and insisting that you "always had those cracks in the plaster". +1 to checking insurance.

Comment: @ AD, why all the talk about level marks and door opening and closing?  The op just was concerned about the temp. posts. They didn't ask about checking if the home was level. This job is early in the process and some minor cracks should be expected. If the GC didn't have insurance his license would be revoked. ( But it is good to know ahead of time.)

Comment: @RMDman  Minor cracks might be expected, but floor sagging not.  Number one thing is to check license/insurance/experience for a major job, but money on less than 50% do, just pick a name from the yellow pages/recommended by friends.

Comment: @ crip659, Where is there any mention from the OP about a floor sagging.  This is my point.  You all are making assumptions about stuff that hasn't happened. The question was about the temp. shoring of the house. not about what might happen if something isn't done correctly.  That is all assumptive and not useful to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit dicey,however the strength of the temporary piers should be fine.

If you are not in an earthquake area, or a hurricane isn't coming in the next 48 hours, I think you are safe.  Remember these guys do this for a living.

Answer (score 0):

Heavy rain poses a danger from soil erosion and from reduction in the soil's bearing capacity. Soil erosion can be easily mitigated with "riprap," where you could dump some gravel around the wood-bearing-on-soil areas. A tarp arranged to shed water away is probably the better solution in this case, though, if there's a soil bearing capacity risk.

Heavy rain will lower the bearing capacity of soil by increasing its moisture content, but the risk in your particular case depends on how that shoring was constructed. That timber beam looks like it has a gap directly under the timber post. This suggests to me that the timber beam is resting on two islands of soil. The exact history of these islands will determine how the system would react to decreases in bearing capacity brought on by increased moisture content. Suppose that these islands were initially deep piles of loose soil, where all of the soil compaction has been provided by your home's dead weight. In this scenario the soil below that timber has no excess capacity, where a reduction in bearing capacity will cause bearing "failure." That's not a catastrophe, however. Because there's lots of area under that beam without soil contact, the area of soil island in contact with the beam would increase under a bearing "failure," quickly finding a new equilibrium after probably a small amount of settlement.

In all likelihood, the soil below that beam was pretty well compacted, though. It's probably undisturbed soil that the beam is sitting on, maybe with a thin layer of poorly compacted soil sandwiched in between. The thinness of this poorly compacted layer would be its saving grace, where it only compresses a teeny fraction of an inch to go from "uncompacted" to "compacted." In this case, there's excess bearing capacity in the soil and the heavy rain probably won't bring the bearing capacity below your home's weight. Even if it did, the unused bearing area under that beam would pick up the slack before any catastrophe.

If you want to mitigate the bearing capacity risk, though, then just prevent the heavy rain from soaking into the area around that shoring. I would use a tarp stapled to the side of the house, and sloping away to a low spot where the water doesn't run back. Amateurs screw it up by building it such that a pond of water accumulates on the tarp and collapses it.

Water running beneath the beam in that open area under the post could negatively impact my "soil islands," so mitigating that risk seems like a good idea. I would pile up soil to an inch or three above the bottom elevation of the beam to prevent any torrent of water from threatening those "islands." The gravel I suggested earlier is more idiot proof, so if instructions to somebody else are relaying through a bunch of intermediaries, then the recommendation is "3 in. depth of clean 3/4 in. gravel."

Answer (score 0):

So that right-most sonotube is for a future post? It's at a corner? Then best-guess your exterior and interior wall paneling are holding up the corner (there are also probably minor contributions from floor panels, wall top plates, and wall bottom plates in decreasing order of relevance). Without the panels holding the wall's studs perpendicular to its top and bottom plates, the corner would sag down to the ground (and make some crackling noises along the way). If it has been fine all of this time, then I wouldn't worry until snow starts accumulating on the roof (assuming that's your climate). The exterior sheathing provides your house's resistance to horizontal loads like wind and earthquake, so its "lateral system" is currently compromised.